# How to use vectors created by P5 createVector as a tensor in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, p5.js

I am using p5 to return the vector path of a drawn line. All the vectors in the line are pushed into an array that holds all the vectors. I'm trying to use this as a tensor but I keep getting an error saying

Error when checking model input: the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got the following list of Tensor(s):
When I opened the array on the dev tool, each vector was printed like this:

0: Vector {p5: p5, x: 0.5150300601202404, y: -0.25450901803607207, z: 0}

could it be the p5 text in the vector array that's giving me the error? Here's my model and fit code:

```
let vectorpath = []; //vector path array

// model, setting layers till next '-----'

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4, inputShape: [2, 2], activation: 'sigmoid'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'sigmoid'}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(model.outputs[0].shape));
model.weights.forEach(w => {
    console.log(w.name, w.shape);
   });

// -----

//this is under the draw function so it is continually updated
const labels = tf.randomUniform([0, 1]);
    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
        console.log('Accuracy', logs.acc);
      }

    model.fit(vectorpath, labels, {
        epochs: 5,
        batchSize: 32,
        callbacks: {onBatchEnd}
    }).then(info => {
        console.log('Final accuracy', info.history.acc);
    });
```

What could be causing the error? and how can I fix it?
The question's pretty vague but I'm really just not sure.